# What is exactly Port 49153 in Angular2+?

Tags: angular, webpack, dockerfile, angular-cli

So i was messing around with a docker file that contain an angular2+ build project, and i have noticed there is 2 port, **4200** (the serving port) and **49153** (for **Webpack Hot Module Reload**).
but i don't get it, what is exactly a **webpack hot module** or **Hot Module Reload**, how much is it necessary in the process of building a project and is it must exposed port?

Answer (score 1):

You may try below one :

I wonder if it would be too much to ask for an optional "--save" parameter/flag to ng serve that would persist the options, like this:

```
ng serve --port 4201 --live-reload-port 50000 --host 0.0.0.0 --save
```

in the above one angular-cli command, there is user defined port and also the webpack file bundling/loading, when you make changes inside your project directory then definately your all file will compile and load on browser.

Comment: so, is it necessary in production mode ?

Comment: no no, its own choice if your really interested to know more, then please go for articles